# ZPL: RFID, Combining Field Data (^FD) and Field Numbers (^FN)

Tags: rfid, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I am attempting to encode the EPC of a GS1 RFID using ZPL statements on a Zebra 410R printer.

First, consider the following ZPL :

```
^FD51,0,6,111111,2,33,444^FS
```

What I am attempting to do, is replace the 444 with a value stored in a field number (^FN).

```
^XA 
^DFE:RFID^FS
^RB96,8,3,3,20,24,10,28
^RFW,E
^FD51,0,6,111111,2,33,^FN11"Enter Barcode"^FS
^XZ
```

So, How do I replace the '444' portion of the field data with the value stored in the field number (^FN11) ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe a little bit too late, but to anyone, who may have the same question - DF is a pair command, you need to pair it with XF. DF is Download format - here you use the varible ( FD, FN). XF is Recall Format - here you declare the variables.
So, your code just miss the definition of variable, here is the whole code:
Your code:

```
^XA 
^DFR:RFID^FS
^RB96,8,3,3,20,24,10,28
^RFW,E
^FD51,0,6,111111,2,33,^FN11"Enter Barcode"^FS
^XZ

^XA
^XFR:RFID
^FN11^FN444^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: This doesnt work? Just tested it in Zebra Designer. To be more explicit, i have the following: ^FDMade In: COUNTRY^FS. I want to replace COUNTRY with a field number, say ^FN1. I know you can split it in two lines, but then you must get the correct x-coordinate.

Comment: Of course this work. Although you can't see the result, because it is command for RFID writing to tag memory. However with RFID printer and RFID reader you can "see" it working :). If you want to replace a part of a string, you have to find the spot by giving it the right coordinates, but the principle is the same. Sample code: ^XA
^DFR:STOREFMT.ZPL^FS
^FO25,25
^AD,36,20^FDMade in:^FS
^FO225,25
^AD,36,20^FN1^FS
^XZ

^XA
^XFR:STOREFMT.ZPL^FS
^FN1^FDMyCountry^FS
^XZ